A question on Rust trait/struct lifetime bounds coercion
I have recently stumbled upon a lifetime coercion issue that I am unable to resolve. The minimal reproducible example which I think stems from the same problem is the following:
const MACGUFFIN: i32 = 0;

trait GiveReference<'a> {
    type Target;
    fn give_reference(&'a self) -> &'a Self::Target;
}
struct Foo<'a>(&'a i32);

impl<'a> GiveReference<'a> for Foo<'a> {
    type Target = i32;
    fn give_reference(&'a self) -> &'a i32 {
        &self.0
    }
}

struct Bar<T, Target>(T, Target);

impl<'a, T: 'a> Bar<T, T::Target>
where
    T: GiveReference<'a> + 'a,
    T::Target: Copy,
{
    pub fn new(foo: T) -> Self {
        let val: <T as GiveReference>::Target = *foo.give_reference();
        Self(foo, val)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo(&MACGUFFIN);

    Bar::new(foo);
}


Fundamentally what I am trying to achieve is to create a container type (think something akin to a readguard) Foo which stores data that may exceed its own lifetime and can return a reference to that data for any lifetime not exceeding its own. I assume that the trait GiveReference and its implementation on Foo satisfies these conditions (Please tell me if this assumption is wrong).
Next, I try to create a secondary container type which stores the initial value of the container/read guard in the form of Bar. In its impl where clause I attempt to make it clear to the compiler that it should only be implemented for GiveReference types which do not outlive their data. However the line:
        let val: <T as GiveReference>::Target = *foo.give_reference();

complains about the foo required to be borrowed for 'a. To my knowledge I would have expected foo.give_reference to instead borrow foo until the end of the copy function, instead of enforcing the lifetime 'a onto the borrow. Can someone please explain to me where my thought pattern breaks down and what, if any, changes can be made to fix the issue.
I have tried reading up a lot more on lifetime coercion in rust, but even after all I see nothing wrong with the general pattern I am attempting to use.

It seems you are trying to use lifetimes which you don't really need, perhaps to make mistakes harder to write. This is acceptable, but this might also lead you into collisions with the compiler. Best to avoid it. If you do somehow need the constraints you pose, please tell us why.

Here is the solution, kudos to @kmdreko:
const MACGUFFIN: i32 = 42;

trait GiveReference {
    type Target;
    fn give_reference(&self) -> &Self::Target;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<'a>(&'a i32);

impl GiveReference for Foo<'_> {
    type Target = i32;
    fn give_reference(&self) -> &i32 {
        &self.0
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bar<T, Target>(T, Target);

impl<T> Bar<T, T::Target>
where
    T: GiveReference,
    T::Target: Copy,
{
    pub fn new(foo: T) -> Self {
        let val: <T as GiveReference>::Target = *foo.give_reference();
        Self(foo, val)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo(&MACGUFFIN);
    let bar = Bar::new(foo);
    println!("{:?}", bar);

    // Proof that it does limit lifetimes:
    let foo2 = Foo(&MACGUFFIN);

    // This works:
    let long_lived_ref = foo2.0;

    // This doesn't:
    //let long_lived_ref = foo2.give_reference();

    drop(foo2);
    println!("{}", long_lived_ref);
}

What's different here to your original code?
Let's look at the same trait with explicit lifetime annotations:

// NO LIFETIME PARAMETER HERE!
trait GiveReference {
    type Target;

    // This lifetime annotation ties the output reference to the
    // lifetime of self, guaranteeing that the returned reference cannot
    // outlive the object.
    fn give_reference<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a Self::Target;
}

The important difference is that this code does not define the lifetime as a trait parameter. A trait parameter would force the user to fix the lifetime to one generic value (as you experienced in your Bar object). Instead, having the lifetime be a parameter of give_reference allows the compiler to resolve it at every call of give_reference. That way the compiler can understand that *foo.give_reference() only requires foo to be borrowed for this single line of code.
So why is it ok to do impl GiveReference for Foo<'_>, essentially not tying the lifetime of give_reference(&self) to the actual stored object in Foo?
That's because an object is implicitly required to not outlive the lifetimes it contains. So anything that implements GiveReference and contains a lifetime is guaranteed to not outlive that lifetime, meaning it is automatically guaranteed that the internally referenced object outlives &self and therefore also &Self::Target.

I understand that that makes the code work, but would that not allow foo.give_reference to give me something with a lifetime unrelated to itself? In this case I could drop foo and still retain the static reference to MACGUFFIN. What I am trying to accomplish is to tie the lifetime of the MACGUFFIN reference returned by foo.give_reference to the lifetime of foo, i.e. not allow anything to hold the reference beyond the lifetime of foo even if the underlying data outlives foo.

Ok true, my phrasing of x outlives y is not great, but not a misunderstanding on my side I believe. When I say outlive, I do refer to moves as well. In this case why is there still a borrow when moving? Why doesn't the borrow stop at *foo.give_reference()? PS I do apologize if it seems like I'm fighting you, I'm not I genuinely appreciate the feedback.

If you want the reference to be tied to foo, then GiveReference doesn't need any lifetime parameters at all. The elided lifetime fn give_reference(&self) -> &Self::Target; already does that. playground link

It seems I my question and the code provided did not exactly reflect the problem I was trying to solve, but thank you @Finomnis and kmdreko for answering my questions regardless. After some digging, I stumbled upon a syntax I was unaware of in rust, see GAT Required Bounds. This was what I was looking for but did not know what to search/ask until I saw it.

For further context (maybe this will help someone in the future), this is the rough initial sketch of what I am working on and I was able to remove <'a> from RwLock<'a> and its downstream dependents thanks to the additional where clauses in the associative types. The issue I had previously was the borrows in FusedSensorObserver::new

Ok I get your problem now - for some reason I didn't realize that you were copying the result and not keeping a reference. Let me think about that for a second.

@ChristoffvanZyl I updated the answer based on kmdreko's comment, which turns out to be exactly what you need.
